# How to display information from my database to html table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

Currently I'm trying to display all the payments I have received that were inserted into my database (payment_history) I want to show them in a html table, but every time I try it, It only shows me 1 user on the html table, but I have more than one user in the SQL table on phpmyadmin.

**Php sided code.**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class payment_history_model extends MY_Model {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getPaymentHistory(){
    $accounts = $this->model->fetch("*", PAYMENT_HISTORY, getDatabyUser(0), "id", "asc");
    if(!empty($accounts)){
        foreach ($accounts as $key => $row) {
            $user = $this->model->get("*", USER_MANAGEMENT, "id = '".$row->uid."'");
            if(!empty($user)){
                $accounts[$key]->user = $user->fullname;
            }else{
                $accounts[$key]->user = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return $accounts;
}
}
```

**My html table code.**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?=l('User')?></th> 
        <th><?=l('Invoice')?></th> 
        <th><?=l('First name')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Last name')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Receiver email')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Payer email')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Package')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Price')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Currency')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Street')?></th>
        <th><?=l('City')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Country')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Payment date')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Payment status')?></th>
        <th><?=l('Option')?></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php  
        if(!empty($result)){
        foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    ?>
    <tr class="pending" data-action="<?=cn('ajax_action_item')?>" data-id="<?=$row->id?>">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="md_checkbox_<?=$key?>" class="filled-in chk-col-red checkItem" value="<?=$row->id?>">
            <label class="p0 m0" for="md_checkbox_<?=$key?>">&nbsp;</label>
        </td>
        <td><a href="<?=url('user_management/update?id='.$row->uid)?>"><?=$row->user?></a></td> 
        <td><?=$row->invoice?></td> 
        <td><?=$row->first_name?></td>
        <td><?=$row->last_name?></td>
        <td><?=$row->receiver_email?></td>
        <td><?=$row->payer_email?></td>
        <td><?=$row->item_name?></td>
        <td><?=$row->mc_gross?></td>
        <td><?=$row->mc_currency?></td>
        <td><?=$row->address_street?></td>
        <td><?=$row->address_city?></td>
        <td><?=$row->address_country?></td>
        <td><?=$row->payment_date?></td>
        <td><?=$row->payment_status?></td>
        <td><?=$row->Option?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Eitan Post database rows into my html table. But its only showing 1 user from my database but theres more than 1 user in the database.

Comment: i dont see you are using any kind of model, do you have it?

Comment: What does this have to do with Laravel? Tagged so I came here but this is either plain php or some other framework, looking at the syntax in your second code block.

Comment: as the man above sais, i dont really see the laravel here my friend

Comment: @Eitan the laravel tag was on accident..

Comment: We need to see `$this->model` class. May be you just need fetchAll instead of fetch or some extra parameters required.

Comment: @LeonidShumakov Is this what you need to see?                                                http://pastebin.com/gut29FaQ - Also I tried FetchAll and it did nothing..

Comment: @HusstianoRonaldo, no most likely we need `MY_Model` or class where fetch() method is implemented.

Comment: @LeonidShumakov This maybe what you need http://pastebin.com/Vc8tUvpH

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your class `MyModel` from http://pastebin.com/Vc8tUvpH contains `fetch` method:

```
function fetch($select = "*", $table = "", $where = "", $order = "", $by = "DESC", $start = -1, $limit = 0, $return_array = false)
{
...
}
```

Now, we can say that the problem can be in `$where = getDatabyUser(0)`.

Most likely `getDatabyUser(0)` adds `where clause` which limits your result to one row.

You should try:

- output `getDatabyUser(0)` like `var_dump(getDatabyUser(0))`
- open phpmyadmin and add the same where clause and check result

Now it looks like you're trying to get payment history for `user with ID = 0`.

You can check it also, by replacing `getDatabyUser(0)` with ""(empty string).

```
public function getPaymentHistory(){
    $accounts = $this->model->fetch("*", PAYMENT_HISTORY, "", "id", "asc");
    if(!empty($accounts)){
        foreach ($accounts as $key => $row) {
            $user = $this->model->get("*", USER_MANAGEMENT, "id = '".$row->uid."'");
            if(!empty($user)){
                $accounts[$key]->user = $user->fullname;
            }else{
                $accounts[$key]->user = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return $accounts;
}
```